# Generate a certificate signing request for an SSL server

Tags: openssl, apache-httpd, ssl, https

I'm running CentOS 6.2 LAMP and I've just purchased an SSL certificate via Namecheap that I'm trying to install on my server. [This](http://www.positivessl.com/ssl-certificate-positivessl.php?tc=1&key5sk1=5026abdb38aa5cd0fe42ad51d848654b71d5a619&key5sk2=&key5sk3=1404988944000&key5sk8=&key5sk9=1404988542000&key5sk10=&key5sk11=1404988951000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=CH3501916153&key6sk3=7&key6sk4=en-us&key6sk5=GB&key6sk6=1&key6sk7=Google&key6sk8=140-1&key6sk9=19201080&key6sk10=true&key6sk11=8615d978f29aa1b0ba2384cc1d3534ee11e6bd55&key6sk12=2035&key7sk1=210159&key1sk1=ors&key1sk2=Google) is the certificate I purchased.

How do I complete this process without the use of a web host?

So far, I have installed SSL using `yum install mod_ssl openssl` and I am now being asked for a CSR via NameCheap and to choose my Server type.

Are `mod_ssl` and `openssl` both in there for Apache2?

[image]

What is a CSR and how do I generate one?

The tutorials I've found online are all using self signed certificates, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so I solved this myself. Unfortunately most of the common documentation on the internet says "As your host to request the CSR". Of course my host is myself so I had to register the code myself on my server.

I established a SSH connection to my server and ran the following command.

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
```

Replace '*myserver*.key' and '*server*.key' with relevant names of your choice. (keep the extensions).

Upon running that command you are then asked several questions:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]: 
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]: 
Locality Name (eg, city) []: 
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: 
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: 
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []: 
Email Address []:
```

Fill this information in and continue, - you'll then be asked for a pass phrase and given the option to choose the company name again.

After this two files are added to your server, usually in the user's home folder. I was logged in as root so they appeared within the "root" folder.

I opened the .csr file with a notepad and copied the contents, I then pasted this in to the NameCheap CSR generation page and continued the wizard.

The rest is self explanatory and I followed other online guides on how to configure the certificates once I had been emailed them from Comodo.